# Skip Standard Error Screen Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Application that you need to register in the db to connect to it but if you are not, there is a Error Screen but its really looking ugly as you can see

[image]

I have tried to check if the session where the user ID is saved == null and than clear Content and this is on the start page where every user is connecting first

```
if (this.Session["SessionId"] ==null)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Write("ERROR");
    Response.End();
}
```

Why do I get here an error

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error.aspx" mode="Off"/>

  </system.web>
```

Thanks for help and fast answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn on the [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) mode of your application in web.config and give a custom page for errors. You will need to set `defaultRedirect` property for unhandled errors.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url" mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly">
   <error statusCode="statuscode" redirect="url"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: You are welcome, you will need to set defaultRedirect property for unhandled errors.

Comment: now I'm getting a a HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error if edited my code

Comment: Can you debug the code and see on what statement you are getting the error?

Comment: if i set a a brake point it is never getting there there is instantly this Error 500.19

Comment: Check if you have valid web.config, the might have introduced some error in web.config.

Comment: You might already have system.web tag and you added another? I assume you have error folder at root having Error.aspx